# Need more information about "Not trusted server certificate" error on Android

Tags: android, ssl

I am developing an iPhone/Android app. One day I noticed that one of the Android phones refused to perform http requests to a server which had a certificate problem. The response body was simply, "Not trusted server certificate". I have seen this error message mentioned in some articles. The thing is, this only happen on **some** Android phones, not all of them. So I am wondering:

1. Is this a User Preference (something like "Refuse to talk to servers with certificate problems") that can be turned on and off on the phone? If so, where can I find it? Is it on or off by default?
2. If this is something that is simply enforced on some Android phones, how many percent of Android phones in the market have this feature?

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting that I am aware of in any android version for what you are asking for.  I would expect most applications to use the default HTTPS handlers.

The not trusted server certificate could be the certificate is not in that device's keystore.  It is possible this error may be handled differently if using the Apache HttpClient instead of the HTTPUrlConnection.  It may be that the system is simply refusing to connect because it can't verify the validity of the server.

Different android versions have different certificates in the keystore.  It appears that as android versions are released, the latest certificates get put in the keystore of that version.  It may be an earlier version of android that does not have the certificate you are looking for.

Most android devices (~45%) are running Gingerbread (android 2.3) which has an older list of certificates.  Close behind is the newer android 4.0 (ice cream and greater) which has an easier method to download and install server certificates.